# Log files rotation with .net listeners

Tags: .net, configuration, logging

I have an **existing** .net service, and I want to configure it to write messages to a log file. I added in the following in the service configuration:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="My.Service" switchValue="All">
      <listeners>
        <add name="text" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\log.txt" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

The problem is that the log file becomes quickly very large, so I was wondering if it's possible to configure some sort of log rotation.
Since the process locks the file for writing, it's not possible to rotate it manually, say with a script periodically renaming the file, at least without stopping and restarting the service.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the [FileLogTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.logging.filelogtracelistener.aspx) that I think would do the trick. You can configure it to a daily or weekly interval.

If it's not enough then you will have to write your own tracelistener, just inherit from TraceListener and override the write methods.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, but I had missed it completely! I wonder why it's defined in the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly instead of System.Diagnostics, anyway, I would think that rotating logs is a fairly common need...

Answer (score 0):

Could you have the log rotation built into the filename so that:

"c:\log.txt"

becomes:

"c:\logDDMMYYYY.txt"

This way the log automatically rolls over to a new file at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may have a look at [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) a free and easy-to-use logging library for .NET. This library already includes log rotating.

Otherwise you'll have your service to "unlock" the file and/or log to a new file automatically.

Comment: Looks promising, but may those logger classes be configured as trace listeners?

Comment: It should...there is a TraceAppender class included. The good point, you may always extend the library and write your own appenders (= where and how log is written)

Comment: oh..I forgot to mention that the library is fully configurable through an separate config file